# Auto-reconnect to a server using a socket in Java

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, connection-timeout

There is a component in my application that listens to a server via TCP (so it only receives data, the output-stream is never used). The only reason for a potential disconnect are technical issues. From a logical point of view, the connection should stay open forever.

I know that I have to implement some kind of ping/pong strategy if I want to detect a connection failure *immediately*. But in my case, it is not necessary to detect a dropped connection immediately as long as it gets detected at all (let's say some minutes or hours later).

My questions:

1. If I don't use some kind of pingpong/alive-check strategy and the connection drops, will I get an IOException in my application logic some time later (it would be okay if it took some hours) or is it possible that the dropped connection isn't detected at all?
2. Would the code below fit my requirements? It's a bit ugly (many try-catch/while(true) and even sleep, but I'm wondering if a timed out connection could be recognized after a certain amount of time (e.g. due to an IOException in the blocking BufferedReader.readLine method).
3. Apart from the questions above, what could I do better?

   ```
   public class Receiver implements Runnable {

   private Socket socket;
   private final String host;
   private final int port;
   private final int connectionRetryAfter = 10* 1000;

   public Receiver(String host, int port)  { // assignments... }

   @Override
   public void run() {
       tryCreateSocket();
       listenToServer();
   }

   private void listenToServer() {
       String receivedLine;
       BufferedReader buf;
       while(true) {
           try {
               buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
               while ((receivedLine = buf.readLine()) != null) {
                   // do something with 'inputLine'
               }
           } catch (IOException e) {
               // logging
           } finally {
               closeSocket();
           }
           // At this point, either an exception occured or the stream equals null (which means it's closed?)
           tryCreateSocket();
       }
   }

   private void tryCreateSocket() {
       try {
           socket = new Socket(host, port);
       } catch (IOException e) {
           // logging
           try {
               Thread.sleep(connectionRetryAfter);
           } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
               // logging
               Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
           }
           // retry
           tryCreateSocket();
       }
   }

   private void closeSocket() {
       if (socket != null) {
           try {
               socket.close();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               // logging
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 2):

`listenToServer()` should certainly throw an `IOException` if the connection/reconnection attempt fails. Consider the case when the server is down. Do you really want to loop inside this method forever?

Comment: Thanks. If the (re)connection attempt fails, there will be an IOException for sure. The question if whether there will be an IOException after a connection was succesfully established and the server goes offline....

Concerning the loop: as the server comes back online, I want the application to reconnect automatically as soon as possible. Is there a more elegant way to achieve this? That piece of code runs in its own thread, so other activities won't be blocked in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

One problem you might need to avoid is that you tryCreateSocket() makes a recursive call. If your client is disconnected for a very long time you might run out of memory. Further more when you do reestablish connection the memory stack is not freed.

I would recommend an iterative while loop calling the tryCreateSocket() to avoid this problem.